# Ошибка в деструкторе __del__ блокировки

Tags: python, многопоточность, tornado

Всем привет! У меня есть примерно такой код, который нуждается в блокировке:

```
self.search_params['my_sex'] = ''
self.search_params['wish_sex'] = 'F'
with (yield self.application.search_lock.acquire()):
   for uid in self.application.inSearch:
      if isComplyUsers(self.search_params, self.application.pool[uid]):
         self.connected(self.uid, uid)
         self.application.inSearch.pop(uid)
         return True

self.application.inSearch.append(self.uid)
```

Сама функция isComplyUsers:

```
  def isComplyUsers(user, user1):
    if(user['my_sex']!='' and user['wish_sex']!='' and user['wish_sex']!=user1['my_sex']):
        return False
     return True
```

self.application.search_lock - tornado.locks.Lock()

Я конечно сократил код, отделив только главные момент из-за чего происходит ошибка.
Иногда в логе выскакиевает ошибка:

```
__del__ future <tornado.object.concurrent.Future object exception
```

И жалуется он на KeyError, и говорит, что 'my_sex' не существует в объекте user. Так вот спрашивается, зачем он вообще вызывает эту функцию в своём деструкторе "__del__". И если я просто буду проверять на пустоту объекта - будет ли это решением проблемы? Также, заметил, что ошибка появляется, только если search_params['my_sex'] = '' именно равен пустоте, если он чему-то не пустому равен, то ошибки не возникает.

Comment: Из приведенного кода совершенно не ясно, для чего используется блокировка. И фраза "там в самой блокировке цикл идёт из пользователей" ясности не добавляет. Приведите больше кода.

Comment: Но мне интересен сам механизм работы блокировок и почему так происходит, как я описал. Дополнив код я только запутую людей

Comment: Дополнил код, чтобы вам было понятно для чего блокировка, чтобы одного человека не могло соеденить с двумя. но причём здесь это - не понятно.

Comment: Во-первых, блокировка должна использоваться в корутине. Во-вторых, как происходит освобождение блокировки?

Comment: это же оператор with, она освобождается сразу после исполнения действия. И что значит "блокировка должна использоваться в корутине"?

Comment: Насчет `with` действительно, блокировка снимается. В остальном, гугл ответит, я думаю.

Comment: Но я искал, не могу найти причины ошибки. Это самое главное. Считай возникает именно при удалении объекта блокировки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45647/discussion-between-nikmoon-and-iproger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы понимаете как работает асинхронность в `tornado`, то принцип работы `tornado.locks.Lock` легко объяснить на примере.

Пусть у нас есть список, который мы хотим защитить от чтения во время редактирования, и от редактирования во время чтения.

```
from tornado import gen, locks

myList = []
listLock = locks.Lock()

@gen.coroutine
def read_list():
    with (yield listLock.acqire()):
        for rec in myList:
            # обработка очередной записи
            # можно использовать асинхронные операции,
            # т.к. редактирование списка все равно заблокировано
            pass

@gen.coroutine
def write_to_list():
    with (yield listLock.acqire()):
        # можно как угодно редактировать список,
        # в том числе используя любые асинхронные функции, т.к.
        # чтение списка заблокировано
        pass
```

Если в описанных функциях не использовать асинхронные операции, блокировка не нужна, т.к. `tornado` работает в одном потоке.

Comment: Спасибо, дописал "@gen.coroutine". Но ошибка осталась. И торнадо не работает в одном потоке. Если бы так было, то при 2000 тысячах одновременных запросах всё бы повисло, а он довольно быстро с ними разбирается и при этом другие запросы тоже выполняются без зависания. Но это же всё абсолютно не важно, ошибка именно в блокировках, и то что она нужна я знаю точно. Потому что пока не было блокировки были ошибки такие что человек соеденялся с кем-то, плюс с ним кто-то соеденялся, то есть одновременно поиск произошёл. Мне интересен механизм их работы внутри, зачем при диструкторе вызывается функция

Comment: Просвещайтесь [про Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html). _To minimize the cost of concurrent connections, Tornado uses a single-threaded event loop._

Comment: Да, только я использую tornado.ioloop.IOLoop

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрев код торнадо оказалось ошибка не в деструкторе происходит!) Просто зачем-то gen.coroutine собирает все ошибки и только при уничтожении объекта возвращает все ошибки которые были. Странно что здесь мне это никто не подсказал. После этого я сразу стал искать ошибку почему могут быть пустые объекты в поиске и нашёл ошибку!)
   **Nikmoon**, Вы были правы, но сразу бы мне сказали, что деструктор возвращает сохранённые ошибки, только тогда бы я понял где искать ошибку, спасибо!)

Comment: Если честно я тоже этого не знал, учтем)